# Как управлять по-разному двумя разными джойстиками(на Canvas) в 3D Unity игре?

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, элементы-управления

Как присвоить разные функции двум разным джойстикам? И как определить, что это они именно были нажаты. Я попытался перерыть матриал по Touch, fingerId, GetComponent,GetTouch и т.д. + так же смотрел инфу по присвоению id объекту, но мне это не особо помогло, или я просто не смог правильно возпользоваться этой 
всей информацией. Так или иначе можете помочь, объяснить или дать подсказку, или дать код(может хотя бы кусочек)

Вот стате содержимое моих файлов со скриптами:
PlayerController.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using CnControls;
using System;

[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerMotor))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 5f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float lookSpeed = 3f;

    private PlayerMotor motor;

    private void Start()
    {
        motor = GetComponent <PlayerMotor> ();
    }



    private void Update()
    {   

        float xMov = CnInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float zMov = CnInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        //Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Vector3 movHor = transform.right * xMov;
        Vector3 movVer = transform.forward * zMov;

        Vector3 velocity = (movHor + movVer).normalized * speed;

        motor.Move(velocity);

       // float yRot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
        //Vector3 rotation = new Vector3(0f, yRot, 0f) * lookSpeed;

        float yRot = CnInputManager.GetAxisRaw(axisName: "Joystick 2");
        Vector3 rotation = new Vector3(0f, yRot, 0f) * lookSpeed;
        motor.Rotate(rotation);

        // float xRot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"); 
        // Vector3 camRotation = new Vector3(xRot, 0f, 0f) * lookSpeed;
        float xRot = CnInputManager.GetAxisRaw(axisName: "Joystick 2");
        Vector3 camRotation = new Vector3(xRot, 0f, 0f) * lookSpeed;

        motor.RotateCam(camRotation);
    }
}
```

PlayerMotor.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using CnControls;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    private Camera cam;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 rotation = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 camRotation = Vector3.zero;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();
    }

    public void Move(Vector3 _velocity)
    {
        velocity = _velocity;
    }

    public void Rotate(Vector3 _rotaton)
    {
        rotation = _rotaton;
    }

    public void RotateCam(Vector3 _camRotaton)
    {
        camRotation = _camRotaton;
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        PerformMove();
        PerformRotation();
    }

    void PerformMove()
    {
        if (velocity != Vector3.zero)
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    void PerformRotation()
    {
        rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(rotation));
        if (cam != null)
            cam.transform.Rotate(-camRotation);
    }
}
```

Стате, компоненты(два джойстика и кнопка) из asset store я использую - CnControls

Очень благодарен заранее.

P.S. Я - глубокий новичок в Unity и С#, так пожалуйста, сильно не злитесь, если вопрос глупый)
Ах и стате, игра - 3D шутер, если её так можно назвать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На активном UI объекте должен висеть Event Trigger через который можно вызвать вот такую процедуру (на нажатие одна процедура, на отпускание другая):

```
public void JoystickTouch(){
    joystickButtonDown = true;

    // пытаемся выяснить, какой ID  касания случился в текущий момент в интересующей нас зоне
    // нельзя исключить, что в один и тот же момент было несколько касаний экрана в указанной зоне, но вероятность этого не очень велика
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if ( touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began &&
            (touch.position.x <= Screen.width/touchScreenSizeMultiplier && touch.position.y <= Screen.height/touchScreenSizeMultiplier) )
                joystickTouchID = touch.fingerId;
    }
}
```

Соотв. получив TouchID можно действовать, к примеру, так:

```
gunSight.transform.position = Input.GetTouch(joystickTouchID).position
```

Соотв. можно все это более тонко обвязать (оперировать массивом касаний, например), но главное принцип ухватить.

Comment: Благодорю, спасибо за ответ, вы очень помогли)
Уверен, в следующих проектах мне это пригодится)